# SQL Server query with CROSS APPLY that includes rows that do not have the CROSS APPLied table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, cross-apply

I have a query...

```
SELECT
i.IncidentID,
i.AccountID,
i.IncidentTypeID,
i.IncidentStateID,
i.CreateDate,
i.LastModifyDate,
i.LastModifyUser,
t.LastModifyDate AS CompletionDate,
(
    SELECT
        COUNT(*)
    FROM
        Actions a
    WHERE
        a.IncidentID = i.IncidentID
) AS ActionCount
FROM
Incidents i CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT
        TOP (1) a.LastModifyDate
    FROM
        Actions a
    WHERE a.IncidentID = i.IncidentID
    ORDER BY
        a.LastModifyDate DESC
) t
WHERE
i.IncidentTypeID = 44
AND i.IncidentStateID = 7
```

...that is getting all `Incidents` and their `Actions`. There's a subquery that's getting an `ActionCount` and a CROSS APPLY that is setting a `CompletionDate` based on the most recently modified action. This is working and accurate, though the issue is that it ignores the Incidents that don't have Actions, so my resultSet is truncated from and expected 25 to 5. Any thoughts on how to clean this up to get a result that sets an ActionCount, CompletionDate and does not leave out the Incidents without Actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `outer apply`:

```
FROM Incidents i OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) a.LastModifyDate
      FROM Actions a
      WHERE a.IncidentID = i.IncidentID
      ORDER BY a.LastModifyDate DESC
     ) t
```

I am curious why you don't eliminate the subquery in the `SELECT` and use:

```
FROM Incidents i OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT MAX(a.LastModifyDate) as LastModifyDate, COUNT(*) as ActionCount
      FROM Actions a
      WHERE a.IncidentID = i.IncidentID
     ) t
```

This would simplify your query.

Comment: Thanks! That breaks the CompletionDate logic, but I can process the results and set that later.